# How can I protect named pipes in windows?

Tags: authentication, windows, appsec

I have some misunderstanding regarding how to secure the communication of named pipes in windows

For example, I have a windows service that talks with other processes via pipes, how can I make sure that I'm talking to the right process? Are there ways of authenticating the connections? I know Chrome implemented some security measures in their code but I was having trouble following the implementation.

I also read about pipe impersonation attacks that can be used against pipes and also was having some trouble understanding how this attacks work or how to block it.

Comment: I think named pipes are simply conduits. The service you run needs to include the security and authentication processes.

Comment: Yes, but how and what? Chrome passes a shared secret to its endpoints in order to authenticate it, so I wanted to know if there are some knows procedures that can be made to improve security

Comment: Then this question is far too broad. There are multiple ways for networked services to authenticate to each other. Encryption, shared secrets, Kerberos, session keys, etc.

Answer (score 3):

From Gray Hat Hacking The Ethical Hacker's Handbook, 4th Edition:

> ### Enumerating Named Pipes
>
> Named pipes are similar to shared sections in
>   that developers used to think, incorrectly, that named pipes accept
>   only trusted, well-formed data from users or programs running at the
>   same privilege level as the program that has created the named pipe.
>   There are (at least) three elevation-of-privilege threats with named
>   pipes. First, weakly ACL’d named pipes can be written to by
>   low-privileged attackers, potentially causing parsing or logic flaws
>   in a program running at a higher privilege level. Second, if attackers
>   can trick higher-privileged users or processes to connect to their
>   named pipe, the attackers may be able to [impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378618(VS.85).aspx) the caller. This
>   impersonation functionality is built into the named pipe
>   infrastructure. Finally, attackers might also find information
>   disclosed from the pipe that they wouldn’t otherwise be able to
>   access. AccessChk does not appear to support named pipes natively, but
>   Mark Russinovich of Sysinternals did create a tool specifically to
>   enumerate named pipes. Here’s the output from [PipeList.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd581625.aspx):

```
PipeList v1.1
by Mark Russinovich
http://www.sysinternals.com
Pipe Name                      Instances      Max Instances
---------                      ---------      -------------
TerminalServer\AutoReconnect        1             1
InitShutdown                        2            -1
lsass                               3            -1
protected_storage                   2            -1
SfApi                               2            -1
ntsvcs                              6            -1
scerpc                              2            -1
net\NtControlPipe1                  1             1
net\NtControlPipe2                  1             1
net\NtControlPipe3                  1             1
```

> The Process Explorer GUI will display the security descriptor for
>   named pipes. The “[squatting](http://www.securityfocus.com/advisories/2472)” or “luring” attack (the second
>   elevation-of-privilege threat previously mentioned) requires an
>   attacker having the SeImpersonatePrivilege to influence the behavior
>   of a process running at a higher privilege level. One such example
>   discovered by Cesar Cerrudo involved an attacker being able to set the
>   file path in the registry for a service’s log file path to an
>   arbitrary value. The attack involved setting the log file path to
>   \??\Pipe\AttackerPipe, creating that named pipe, causing an event to
>   be logged, and impersonating the LocalSystem caller connecting to
>   \??\Pipe\AttackerPipe.